# Populate excel cell value from a different sheet based on value in a column

Tags: excel

I have different excel sheets and I am trying to populate values into one sheet from another sheet by comparing the values

Sheet 1 is like below

[image]

Sheet 2 has below columns

[image]

Now if the name is same, I want to populate Email & Mobile to Sheet 1 from Sheet 2

I tried using VLOOKUP, but I am not able to get the syntax right. Any help is appreciated.

Hope my question is clear, please feel free to drop in a comment if you need any clarification, thanks

Comment: Do you mind showing a screen shot? Your post isn't clear. So does Sheet1 have Name | Age | DoB | Email ID | Mobile # | ... ?

Comment: thanks for asking, I've added screenshots, please let me know if you need any clarifications

Comment: Just as I thought. Look at my answer it should work fine now.

Answer (score 1):

for the email:

```
=vlookup(a2, sheet2!A:C, 2, false)
```

for the Mobile #:

```
=vlookup(a2, sheet2!A:C, 3, false)
```

[image: This is what Sheet1 will look like]

Comment: thanks for the help, just a quick question, why is it a4 here inside the vlookup?

Comment: lol, because "A4" was where 'John' is located. In your case, it will be "A2".

Comment: ah gotcha, I selected the column and the formula got changed to [@[Name]] and it worked fine, thanks for your help